# I have my LiDAR point cloud with a Cartesian CS. I took three ground control points. I would like to convert it to Geographic Coordinate systems

Tags: python, r

[Here is the ground control points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxaa9.png)
Thank you.

I have tried to use cloud compare to align this point cloud with the ground cloud points but the latitude and longitude values was not in alignments with the actual Geographic Coordinate system.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have a lidar point cloud with a cartesian coordinate system. my three ground control points are in world geographic coordinate systems (WGS84). I would like to use these ground control points to georeference the data. However, after several trials using cloud compare, it is either the point cloud ends up occupying a bigger area or smaller than usual whenever I try to visualize it in ArcGIS.

Comment: Could you put it in the question, so it's more useful? Thanks!